# How to Display Both Text and Check box on same Line in ChecklistBox

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net, webforms

I have used CheckListBox Control to Display List of Items. I want to Display both text and check box on same line but for Larger text it breaks down Text into next line like this

[image]

My Aspx Tag :

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="ChkLstProducts" runat="server" DataTextField="ProductName" DataValueField="ProductId" CssClass="productsf" Width="300"></asp:CheckBoxList>
```

CSS code:

```
.productsf {
    font-family: 'Segoe UI';
    font-size: 10px;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    color: #000;
    cursor: pointer;
    display:list-item
}
```

Comment: just widen your list

Comment: you haven't given a width so the ellipsis won;t work

Comment: i specified it on aspx tag Width="300" @rachelGallen